# How do I set the $event returnValue property to null in typeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using the window.beforeunload event to trap for data changes and warn the user if they need to save data. According to the Mozilla online docs if I set the event return value to null I will not get a user prompt and the event will be handled silently.

"When this event returns (or sets the returnValue property to) a value other than null or undefined, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. "

However, I have tried setting the return value to null and undefined and it is getting treated as the string representations not the actual values. The code below shows my event handler.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload',['$event'])
  onUnload(e){

  e.returnValue = undefined;
  if(e.returnValue == "undefined"){
    console.log("Treated like string");
  }
  if(e.returnValue == undefined){
    console.log("treated like null value");
  }

}
```

The first if condition is firing in all instances whether I try undefined or null. I have verified that the second if statement is not true.

I don't get the same behavior if I create a new variable and assign its value. It looks like this is some kind of constraint on the returnValue property of the event. Is there a simple solution to this problem.

Comment: What if you use `return null`?

Comment: OK, that is part of the answer. I tried that yesterday also but I still set the returnValue and apparently that overrides the return statement. If I explicitly call return(null) without setting the returnValue of the event then it works as expected.

Comment: if(isDirty()){return(true)}else{return(null)}

Answer (score 1):

From MDN web docs:

> If a string is assigned to the returnValue Event property, a dialog appears asking the user for confirmation to leave the page (see example below). Some browsers display the returned string in the dialog box, but others display their own message. If no value is provided, the event is processed silently.

Please, check the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) for more detail on `beforeunload` event.

---

```
  public get hasUnsavedData(): boolean {
    // some logic
    return false;
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload',['$event'])
  onUnload(e){
    if (this.hasUnsavedData) {
      e.returnValue = 'You have unsaved changes...';
    }
    return;
  }
```

Comment: I understand the functionality and when the dialog box will be displayed. The issue is that for some reason I cannot set the returnValue to null. It insists on being treated like the string "null" and that triggers the confirmation message.

Comment: Got it. I've updated my answer and added an example. The idea is - if you want to show dialog, then you just have to assign to `returnValue` the Modal dialog text. But not all browsers support custom dialog texts. For example, in chrome you will see the standard text 'Changes you made may not be saved.'
If user does not have any unsaved data - you just simply call `return`. Hope this will help you. I've created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrpe8e?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Posting here because this is too long to include in a comment.

I have gotten this working based on the suggestion from Explosion Pills above. I am not trying to set a custom message. The confusing point here is that in the debugger the unset returnValue appears as the empty string "" and not the null value. Therefore I was trying to set it to null in order to satisfy the MDN requirement. This is what was not working as I explained above. The apparent required behavior is to set the returnValue to any string if you want to get the dialog and DO NOT set the return value but just call return(null) if you do not want the dialog. This is confusing because it is an unbalanced function. Calling return("true") will not trigger the dialog. You must set the returnValue property explicitly to trigger the dialog and you must NOT set this value if you don't want to trigger the dialog. 
I am runnning inside Angular and using the @HostListener so this might be a side effect of that environment.

Comment: If you can, would you please share a code snippet of this last explanation?